# Multiple particle emittion locations

Tags: c#, monogame, particles

I was following this tutorial on particle systems in XNA: http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/2d-particle-engine-1
and its a fine tutorial, but I can't find a easy way to have the particles emit from multiple locations properly. I tried to put

`particleEngine.EmitterLocation = new Vector2(Mouse.GetState().X, Mouse.GetState().Y);`
and

```
particleEngine.Update();
```

in a loop for every place I want it to appear, but it speeds up the particles (since it is being "updated" multiple times per Update). Any way to fix this? Thanks!

EDIT: Just to clarify, I want to know how to make particles emit from multiple locations, not why it is updating multiple times per update